# MariaDB 0th day?

Tags: mariadb, date

[image]

Today is the 2nd of october, I added a line to my table using curdate() -2 and now it shows the 0th of October when it's supposed to show September 30th. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special date math built in to make `date + number` mean add a number of days to the date. Instead, it is converting your date implicitly to a number and then doing the math, returning a number.

Instead, you should use the `date_add` function:

```
select date_add(curdate(),  interval -2 day);
```

[DbFiddle to demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b2130b9b5947c3305d9b8b1c6335e4d1)